# Type Assertion null to undefined

Tags: typescript

I was wondering why TypeScript is not showing an error in this type assertion, where `null`  is assigned to a property that expects `number | undefined`?

[typescriptlang example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgjFAvFA3gKCpqA3AhgGwFcIAuKAO0IFsAjCAJygB8LD980BfNUSWAJiSoMWPEQgB+MpVoMuAbjRoAxgHtyAZ2A44ZeEPRYcBYtLYdOitZu3Z+ewckOiTpHQDoxxLivVacAMwGIpgA9KEUqlAM9Kr0IcbiZNhwnq5cULgaAkA)

```js
type T1 = {
    value: number | null
}
type T2 = {
    value?: number
};

const v1: T1 = {
    value: null
};
const v2: T2 = {
    // error, as expected
    value: v1.value
}
const v3 = {
    // no error
    value: v1.value
} as T2
```

I would have expected that this type assertion would only be possible, if you assert it to `unknown` first.

```js
const v4 = ({
    value: v1.value
} as unknown) as T2
```

In the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) it is said that

> TypeScript only allows type assertions which convert to a more specific or less specific version of a type.

Is the type becoming more specific or less specific?

Comment: You are doing a type assertion on a type that is partially compatible. Why would you except an error ?

Comment: because type assertions allow you to override the inferred type of a value. In this case, TypeScript infers that v1.value is of type number | null, but when you assert it as T2, you are telling TypeScript that it is of type { value?: number }, which is a more specific type (since it has a narrower set of possible values) than number | null

Comment: `as` tells TS to use this type "as though" it's the other type. In this case TS only checks if the types are compatible. It does not check if they are the same type. Any object is compatible with `T2` because `T2` can be `{}`

Answer (score 0):

At [typescript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) you can read the next line

> Reminder: Because type assertions are removed at compile-time, there is no runtime checking associated with a type assertion. There won’t be an exception or null generated if the type assertion is wrong.

And that's why it's not showing the error. Not related to scecificity